# Jade variable in variable

Tags: variables, pug

I have a .jade file with only variables. One of them is a variable which begins with a variable defined before it.

example:

My variables.jade file:

```
- var baseurl = 'http://example.com'
- var assets = baserurl+'/assets'
- var images = assets+'/images'
```

My main.jade file:

```
include variables
img(src=images+'/1.jpg')
```

The html will be:

```
<img src='undefined/assets/images/1.jpg'>
```

Why does the baseurl appear as undefined?

Comment: This question should be deleted as it is solved by fixing a simple typographical error (change `baserurl` to `baseurl`) See help page here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typo in `baserurl`. it should be `baseurl`